# How to append data with jquery using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, for-loop

I am trying to add this to a div in my document but the selection items are all stacking on top of each other even though I'm setting them up in different columns. I think its because I am looping through it and its creating an exact copy of itself and they're stacking on each other. CSS wont fix it either. I've tried wrapping the col-md-3 class outside of the div thats outputting the javascript no luck. I'm really stuck. When I've used React its been easy to do stuff like this with JSX, but I'm having trouble here. Also I should mention that the classes aren't linked to any css. I just named them but they don't do anything. All the styles are inline and can be seen in the jquery.

```
for (var i = 0; i < works.length; i++) {
    $('#work-items').append("\
        <div class='col-md-3'>\
            <div class='portfolio-item'>\
                <span class='work-name'" + works[i].name + " ></span>\
                <a href='" + works[i].link + "' class='work-img weblink' style='text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon'>\
                    <img class='img-responsive img-thumbnail' style='height: 150px; width: 300px' src='" + works[i].pic + "'>\
                    <span class='info'><p class='proj-title'></p>" + works[i].title + " </span >  \
                </a >\
                <a href='" + works[i].github + "' class='work-img github' style = 'text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em' > \
                </a >\
            </div >\
         </div >\
    ");
}
```

I doubt this is needed but heres the array of objects I'm getting the data from.

```
var works = [
    {
        name: "Ruby on Rails | Javascript",
        title: "Ecommerce Application",
        pic: "img/workimg/BikesberlinCollage.jpg",
        link: "https://bikesberlinworldwide.herokuapp.com",
        github: "https://github.com/bklynbest/Bikeshop-Ecommerce-app"
    },

    {
        name: "Ruby on Rails | Vue",
        title: "Project Manager",
        pic: "img/workimg/projekt.png",
        link: "https://britanniaprojectmanager.herokuapp.com",
        github: "https://github.com/bklynbest/projektmanager"
    },
]
```

[Link to  HTML/CSS Output](https://prnt.sc/m7rlgx)
Here is the rendered HTML

```
<html lang="en">


<body>
   <div class="container">
    <h1 class="name">jJonathan</h1>
    <h4 class="title">...</h4>
 </div>
<div class="container">

    <div id="work-items" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" ruby="" on="" rails="" |="" javascript=""></span> <a href="https://bikesberlinworldwide.herokuapp.com" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">         <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/BikesberlinCollage.jpg">         <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Ecommerce Application</span>           </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/Bikeshop-Ecommerce-app" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github            </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" ruby="" on="" rails="" |="" vue=""></span> <a href="https://britanniaprojectmanager.herokuapp.com" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">         <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/projekt.png">            <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Project Manager</span>             </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/projektmanager" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github            </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" ruby="" on="" rails="" |="" javascript=""></span> <a href="https://britanniarecipebox.herokuapp.com/" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">          <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/recipeapp.png">          <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Recipe Sharing App</span>              </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/recipebox" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github         </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" ruby="" on="" rails=""></span> <a href="https://jobs495.herokuapp.com" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">         <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/jobs.png">           <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Job Board Application</span>           </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/britanniajobs" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github         </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" javascript="" |="" react=""></span> <a href="https://britaninaweather.netlify.com/" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">            <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/weather.png">            <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Weather Checker</span>             </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/britanniaWeather" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github          </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" react="" |="" firebase="" redux=""></span> <a href="https://britannia-planner.firebaseapp.com/" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">            <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/planner.png">            <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Planner</span>             </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/planner" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github           </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" javascript=""></span> <a href="https://coolform.netlify.com/" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">          <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/form.png">           <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>Javascript Form</span>             </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/coolform" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github          </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolio-item"> <span class="work-name" javascript="" |="" react=""></span> <a href="https://brianniachat.netlify.com/" class="work-img weblink" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.2em; color:salmon">            <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height: 150px; width: 300px" src="img/workimg/reactchat.png">          <span class="info"><p class="proj-title"></p>React Chat App</span>              </a>                    <a href="https://github.com/bklynbest/reactchatapp" class="work-img github" style="text-decoration: none; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: 1.2em"> Github          </a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/work.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post the post-rendered CSS/HTML?  It would help determine the outcome formatting vs guessing the extra formatting that's on the page.

Comment: I just did thanks for taking a look.

Comment: That's just a screenshot.  Post the actual HTML/CSS generated (the source code) preferably here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap I have to ask if the `#work-items` has a class of "row".

Besides that, one wonders if the css for any of the non-bootstrap elements you are adding, here, is getting in the way.
If you replace all of the html inside `col-md-3` with simple `works[i].link` does the wrong behavior still occur?

Comment: It currently does not include row, but I've included it before and just now when you mentioned it. Still no luck.

Comment: and replacing the html with just the one string?  And the `row` *is* further wrapped in a `container`, yes?

Comment: ok, looking at your screenshots it is fairly clear that the portfolio-related items aren't the problem.  My developer-senses, however, are tingling and I'm pretty darn positive you didn't wrap everything in a `container` of some sort

Comment: Wrap the work items div in a container within the html? I've done that. I shouldve posted it but my html is just a container with an h1 and h2 tag. And right underneath is my #work-items div. I've wrapped it in a container, and done it without one and still have the same issue.

Comment: No, wrap it in a `container`... that is to say, the container tag should have `class="container"` ... no offence but you *really* need to read the docs a lot better if you are going to be able to use bootstrap without coming here with a question every few hours....

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it properly. But I did wrap it in a container like that. I've used bootstrap many times before, bulma as well. I honestly think its the way I've written my Jquery. I don't usually use it.

Comment: please paste the final html as it appears in your dev tools

Comment: I pasted it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That looks right to me... literally the only thing I can think of now is that I don't see you including the bootstrap css file anywhere... aside from that we're back to something in the portfolio/workitem related classes are messing with the css and you should try it without any of the inner html, just `works[i].link` as a starting point

Comment: You were right. I had a space in my bootstrap CDN link. I'm embarrassed to even admit this.

Comment: Typos happen :-)

Comment: Hmmmmm... I wonder what the correct stackoverflow etiquette is, here?  Are you supposed to mark my answer as correct because down the line in the comments I eventually gave you the correct answer?  Am I supposed to create a new answer and you mark *that* as correct?

Comment: I realize that probably seemed passive-aggressive... I assure you I was just "thinking out loud" so-to-speak.   Thanks, tho!

Comment: Haha no. I was actually thinking that from the get go. I just forgot to get around to it. Lol. Kò worries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on **padding** and **margin** provided to the CSS classes `portfolio-item` and `work-items` also can you try once with `col-lg-3` class, I doubt your screen resolution may be leading to the view optimized for mobile where **divs** are stacked oon top of each other, although in the snapshot the screen size doesn't appear to be an issue.

Comment: I just tried  `col-lg-3` no luck. And I removed all css classes from portfolio item and work items and had the same issue. The way they're set up in the snapshot is with work-items set to `position: relative` if I set it to absolute they all stack directly on top of one another.

Comment: Can you please share the CSS code for all the styling classes that you have added on top of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Spent hours trying to figure this out. Thanks alot for the help. I had an extra character in my bootstrap CDN link. Sorry for wasting everyone's time -_-.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the code you provided works as expected in a minimal environment (which means you should inspect your `.col-` elements and see which rule messes the `position` property), here's how you can create and apply a template over an array of items:

#### How to append data to DOM using a loop or `.map()`

```js
var works = [{
    name: "Ruby on Rails | Javascript",
    title: "Ecommerce Application",
    pic: "img/workimg/BikesberlinCollage.jpg",
    link: "https://bikesberlinworldwide.herokuapp.com",
    github: "https://github.com/bklynbest/Bikeshop-Ecommerce-app"
  },
  {
    name: "Ruby on Rails | Vue",
    title: "Project Manager",
    pic: "img/workimg/projekt.png",
    link: "https://britanniaprojectmanager.herokuapp.com",
    github: "https://github.com/bklynbest/projektmanager"
  }
];

const template_item = ({name,title,pic,link,github}) => `
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <h4 class="work-name">${name}</h4>
    <a href="${link}" class="work-img weblink">
      <img class="work-thumb img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="${pic}" alt="${title}">
    </a>
    <p>
      <a href="${link}" class="work-link">${title}</a>
      <a href="${github}" class="work-github"> GitHub: ${github.substring(github.lastIndexOf("/")+1)}</a> 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>`;

const items = works.map(template_item);

$('#work-items').append(items);
```

```css
.work-img {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.work-thumb.img-thumbnail {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}

.work-link,
.work-github {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: salmon;
}
.work-github {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="work-items" class="row"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

PS:

- Loop only to create/concatenate strings or prepopulate an array with your items Elements
- Append only once! (not multiple times inside a loop)
- Don't wrap `<p>` inside `<span>`
- Do use `alt` tags